# Is there any way to change which button I use to shoot?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I poked around in a bunch of menus, and found a lot of interesting stuff, but I couldn't find any way to change the controls. I would love to be able to move the shooting button to the left trigger on the Circle Pad Pro, or to the R button. Is that possible? Or am I stuck with having a sore pinky forever and ever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit all the controls of the game via the **Control Configuration menu.**

**Options > Controls > Control Configuration** (step 3 will allow you to change your shoot button)

Comment: .....how did I miss this. :(

Comment: Look on the bright side, at least  I've gained some rep! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can shoot with the L-Button, or using A or B I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>, or just <kbd>L</kbd>. It helps to melee using <kbd>L</kbd>.